# Xcode Project broken after renaming and rebuilding (App cleaned, and ran at the same time, and schemes broke)

Tags: ios, xcode, build, code-cleanup

I was renaming my app from "App's Name?" to "Apps Name", removing the question mark and apostrophe, to prevent the error "A signed resource has already been added, modified, or deleted". However, at one point, the project seemed to clean itself and try building/running at the same time, which caused the build to fail. So I closed and reopened Xcode, and the project is now broken. I can't save it, or build or clean it (all these options are greyed out in the menu). It shows a wheel next to my project and says my device is ineligible, whilst not allowing me to switch to any simulators.

I addition, when I try changing the app name in the File Inspector, and hit enter, the following popup appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezy9M.png

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: So I think I've found out it's to do with the Schemes messing up. Here's a screenshot of my Schemes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS0Ix.png

So, is there any way to remove the other 2 schemes, leaving just the one in the middle? This may fix my issue.

EDIT 2: So I've solved the issue by going into "Edit Schemes", and changing the executable in the "Run" section to be the same as the scheme I wanted to use, rather than being "Ask on launch". Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: are you using Time Machine (built into MacOS)?

Comment: I haven't knowingly used it before, why? I have only had my mac for 2-3 weeks. EDIT: I just checked and Time Machine is off :\

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I've solved the issue by going into "Edit Schemes", and changing the executable in the "Run" section to be the same as the scheme I wanted to use, rather than being "Ask on launch". Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Just renaiming the bundle displayName works . In xcode 6 app name is accociated with module name so when you change the name it conflicts with schemes. Its safe to just change the BundleDisplay name in info.plist if you wish to change the app display name only